# How to install R 2.15.3 on Mac OS X 10.11?

Tags: r, macos

I'm using Mac OSX 10.11.6 and I would like to be able to install an older R version, namely R 2.15.3.  I tried installing from the R 2.15.3.pkg file I downloaded from CRAN, but it says "R 2.15.3 for Mac OS X 10.5 or higher (Leopard build) can't be installed on this disk. Use Tiger build (available from CRAN) for older systems."

Does anyone know if there are binaries available to do this?  Or, can I install it from source somehow, and if so, are there any potential pitfalls (e.g. interference with latest R install).  Maybe I'm just out of luck?

Comment: R is pretty conservative in the changes it makes; they don't make many breaking changes, so old packages should in almost every case load fine on new versions of R. That said, if you're going to try to install old R on new OS X, you'll probably have to build from source, which will almost certainly get finicky.

Comment: I'd highly suggest installing Docker and doing this in a container. It may be a bit of extra up-front work, but you can build a fully reproducible workflow environment this way and avoid any potential issues with a 2.15.3 install on your primary system.

Comment: I was able to install a working version of sp on R 3.3.1, so I have modified the question appropriately.  I will look into using Docker as I have researched that before, and it makes sense to try in this case, but I still am not sure how best to install R 2.15.3 on Mac OS 10.11.6.  It sounds as though I will have to build it from source...